# GetInitialState Setting One Element But Not The Other

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, qr-code

Seemingly irrational behavior in my React code. I set two elements inside to state elements one line of code after the other. I have console.log'ed out each. Both properly print previous to assignment, yet only the bitcoin wallet variable (wallet) is properly represented in state and not imageLink.

```
module.exports = React.createClass({
   getInitialState: function() {
     return {
       walletAddress: null,
       image: null,
    };
   }, 
   componentWillMount: function() {
    Parse.User.currentAsync()
     .then((user) => { 
      var wallet = user.get('address');
      var imageLink = `https://api.qrserver.com/v1/create-qr-code/?size=500x500&data=bitcoin:${wallet}`;
      console.log("wallet", wallet);
      console.log("image: ", imageLink);
      this.setState({image: imageLink});
      this.setState({walletAddress: wallet});
      console.log("imagezzz: ", this.state.imageLink);
   })
 },
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Should add, I've also tried setting both state elements within one assignment ie: this.setState({image: imageLink, walletAddress: wallet});. Which also did not change the outcome.

Comment: It looks like you're logging `state.imageLink` (on the `console.log("imagezzz"...` line) but you're setting `state.image`.

Answer (score 0):

Very basic mistake, I was assigning to this.state.image and attempting to log, this.state.imageLink.

I syntax error on my part, all else works fine. Thanks to @James Allardice for the clarifying comment.